# Icon name for unlocked keyring

Tags: icons, gtk, pygtk

I am working on a program and I want to implement icon denoting keyring state. If you start `seahorse` you'll see it has the same icon of padlock in two states, locked and unlocked.

I am unable to find unlocked icon name. There are many locked padlocks in `/usr/share/icons` but I didn't find any unlocked icons.

So, my question is, what's the name of the icon I can use with `set_from_icon_name` method.

Note: `stock_lock-open` is not the one am looking for.

Comment: When I start seahorse I see two keys on a keyring, not padlocks. Are you using Ubuntu 12.04 or 12.10, and have you installed any themes?

Comment: Nevermind, I think I see what you mean in the newer version in 12.10. Browsing the [package file list](http://packages.ubuntu.com/da/quantal-updates/i386/seahorse/filelist) online, it appears there are multiple icon files also in **/usr/share/seahorse/icons/hicolor/???** Does that help? I'm on 12.04 so unfortunately I can't see the same thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go, taken from the Seahorse source:

```
from gi.repository import Gtk, Gio

icon_theme = Gtk.IconTheme.get_default()
def get_pixbuf_from_themed_icon(name, size):
    icon = Gio.ThemedIcon.new_with_default_fallbacks(name)
    icon_info = icon_theme.lookup_by_gicon(icon, size, 0)
    return icon_info.load_icon()

pixbuf_lock = get_pixbuf_from_themed_icon("changes-prevent-symbolic", 48)
pixbuf_unlock = get_pixbuf_from_themed_icon("changes-allow-symbolic", 48)

win = Gtk.Window()
win.resize(300, 300)
win.connect('delete-event', Gtk.main_quit)

vbox = Gtk.VBox(False, 4)
img_lock = Gtk.Image.new_from_pixbuf(pixbuf_lock)
vbox.pack_start(img_lock, False, False, 0)
img_unlock = Gtk.Image.new_from_pixbuf(pixbuf_unlock)
vbox.pack_start(img_unlock, False, False, 0)

win.add(vbox)
win.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

Only problem is the dark version. I couldn't translate the `create_spotlight_pixbuf` function to Python.

You might also want to look at the [`GtkLockButton`](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/3.6/GtkLockButton.html).

Comment: I've found solution to this problem little earlier but it's the same solution. Thanks, marking as accepted.